# Why does riseOnHover not work?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am attempting to get my markers in a leaflet plot to popup and show their content when the mouse hovers over the marker. The code I am trying does not seem to work. The aim is to integrate this into a Shiny web application.

```
m <- leaflet() %>% 
setView(lat = 51.50862, lng = -0.128069, zoom = 16) %>% 
addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(lng = c(-0.128369,-0.128169,-0.128500), lat = c(51.50862,51.50790,51.50962),
popup = 'c', options = markerOptions(clickable = TRUE, draggable = FALSE, 
keyboard = TRUE, title = "", alt = "", zIndexOffset = 0, opacity = 1, 
riseOnHover = TRUE, riseOffset = 250)) 
m
```

Is there any reason that this doesn't work? Any suggestions / help would be much appreciated.

Will

Comment: The documentation says `If true, the marker will get on top of others when you hover the mouse over it.` I suspect this means that if you have a number of overlapping markers, the one with the mouse over will rise over the rest.

Comment: Thanks, however when zoomed in on the points and I try to hover over it still does not work even though there is no overlap between markers

Comment: I think you have it backwards. When you zoom out, marker pops up when you hover over it. I have checked this by setting `riseOnHover = FALSE` and they indeed do not move when hovered over.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I misunderstood how the riseOnHover function worked. Thank you. Do you happen to know a way to get the content to popup when the mouse is over the marker?

Comment: Sorry, I think leaflet/javascript(?) people will be better suited to answer that question.

Comment: See this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/how-to-show-a-popup-on-mouse-over-not-on-click)